# Rails is re-parsing a ruby file in lib/ for every asset request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Rails version:  3.1 
Ruby version: 1.9.2

In one of my current projects, I am getting dozens of "warning: already initialized constant" lines in the log for every request.   The constant in question is in a module defined in lib.

I was entirely baffled as to why Rails is parsing this file up to 80 times per request, until I happened to turn on caching in development mode this morning (to test something else) and noticed that Rails is reporting a cache miss between each of those lines.  This is the first 4 of ~80 such notifications when loading the homepage:

```
/Users/evan/Development/Ruby/apps/thefriendex/lib/feeds_mixin.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_LIMIT
cache: [GET /assets/application.css?body=1] miss
/Users/evan/Development/Ruby/apps/thefriendex/lib/feeds_mixin.rb:2: warning: already     initialized constant DEFAULT_LIMIT
cache: [GET /assets/_have_need_bar.css?body=1] miss
/Users/evan/Development/Ruby/apps/thefriendex/lib/feeds_mixin.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_LIMIT
cache: [GET /assets/admin.css?body=1] miss
/Users/evan/Development/Ruby/apps/thefriendex/lib/feeds_mixin.rb:2: warning: already     initialized constant DEFAULT_LIMIT
cache: [GET /assets/blurb_ad.css?body=1] miss
```

So it looks like it's re-parsing lib/feeds_mixin.rb again for each and every asset request.   I used to have a config line adding lib/*.rb to the autoload paths, but I've removed that to no effect.

The module in question is just a straightforward module with one constant and three instance methods.  It's mixed in to two controllers via a straightforward include, I can add that code if necessary.

Any thoughts on why this file would be getting reparsed every time an asset is requested?

CODE: The mixin  (lib/feeds_mixin.rb)

```
module FeedsMixin
  DEFAULT_LIMIT = 6

  def friends_feed_items(opts = {})
     # do stuff
  end

  def friends_of_friends_feed_items(opts = {})
     # do stuff
  end

  def community_feed_items(opts = {})
    # do stuff
  end

  def build_feed_hash(type, items, opts) 
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

CODE:  where it's included (lib/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb)
(one other controller is very similar to this one)

```
require 'feeds_mixin'
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable
  include FeedsMixin
  layout 'dashboard'
  before_filter :require_user, :set_feeds

  LIMIT = 6
  DEFAULT_DATE_THRESHHOLD = 14.days

  def index
  end

  def set_feeds
    @friends_feed = friends_feed_items(:since => since_date, :limit => LIMIT)
    @friends_of_friends_feed = friends_of_friends_feed_items(:since => since_date, :limit => LIMIT)
    @community_feed = community_feed_items(:since => since_date, :limit => LIMIT)
  end

  def since_date
    DEFAULT_DATE_THRESHHOLD.ago
  end
  memoize :since_date
end
```

Comment: The code would be useful. You could also try to add `puts caller` just before or after you define the constant to output the current calling stack, that might give a clue what's going on.

Comment: Updated to add code.   Trying caller now and will post further update.

Comment: I think there was a "bug" at some point in rails 3.1 where when you were using observers, the whole environment was reloaded by rails for each assets. No idea if it's related, but might be an idea.